# "Могущий" — можно ли так сказать?

Tags: словообразование

Подскажите, пожалуйста, образуется ли причастие от глагола "мочь"? Можно ли сказать "могущий сделать то-то и то-то"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, от глагола мочь образуется причастие могУщий.  Правда, на практике  чаще говорят "который может".

Comment: Могущий

Новый толково-словообразовательный словарь русского языка. Автор Т. Ф. Ефремова.
могУщий прил. устар. То же, что: могучий (2*).



Толковый словарь русского языка под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова
МОГУЩИЙ могущая, могущее (книжн.). 

1. Прич. наст. вр. от мочь. 

2. Могучий (устар.). Незримый хранитель могущему дан. Пушкин.